# Laravel production app not reflecting js. changes

Tags: laravel, webpack

I have a problem with laravel app that is in production. I have some changes that are in js files (Vue) but theese changes do not reflect on website no matter what I do. I tried the following commands that did not help: `php artisan optimize:clear` and `npm update`.

This is the output I get for `npm run dev`:

```
cross-var $npm_execpath run development -- --watch
```

And here is output of `npm run prod`:

```
cross-var $npm_execpath run production
```

Following is what I have currently in webpack config (webpack.mix.js) :

```
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version().options({
        // Optimize JS minification process         
        terser: {             
            cache: true,             
            parallel: true,             
            sourceMap: true         
        }     
    }); 
} else {
    // Uses inline source-maps on development     
    mix.webpackConfig({         
       devtool: "inline-source-map",     
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Did you recompile your assets after making changes?

Comment: hey, so this is what i get when i try to run "npm run watch" 
`cross-var $npm_execpath run development -- --watch`

Comment: If you're developing use `npm run dev`, if you make changes often you can use `npm run watch`, if you're in production use `npm run prod`. Since you're in production run `npm run prod`. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of that command

Comment: Sure ! I added it to the post, netiher seem to work for some rason

Comment: Open console browser. By default with console opened cache is disable

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Version your Laravel mix to run only in production mode

```
// Point to the right app.js folder depending on the Laravel version you are using
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

### 2. Call the versioned mix js file in your blade using the mix() Laravel helper function

```php
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Every time your run npm run production, a new version of the mix is created purging the one cached on browsers hence reflecting the current code functionalities

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will give it a shot and update, ty

Comment: this is what i have currently in webpack config (webpack.mix.js) : 

`if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version().options({
        // Optimize JS minification process
        terser: {
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: true
        }
    });
} else {
    // Uses inline source-maps on development
    mix.webpackConfig({
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
    });
}`

Comment: if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}. Even if you don't chain the option method, it works properly, Let the version() use the default properties

Comment: Also this is what i just noticed this error: 

`Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory`

Comment: does this file .babelrc exist in your root directory

Comment: Yes, and this is the contents : 

`{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "forceAllTransforms": true,
            "targets": {
                "node": "current"
            }
        }]
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true
}
`

Comment: ` {     
  "presets": [ 
  "@babel/preset-env", 
  "sourceMaps": true,
  {             
   "forceAllTransforms": true,             
   "targets": {                 
    "node": "current"             
   }         
  }     
  ] 
  
 }` try this

Comment: no :( 

this is ooutput :

`.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Expected ']' instead of ':' at line 4 column 14 of the JSON5 data. Still to read: ": true,\n { \"forceAll" (While processing preset:`

Comment: Try this : `{     
  "presets": [ 
  "@babel/preset-env", 
  {             
   "forceAllTransforms": true,             
   "targets": {                 
    "node": "current"             
   }         
  }     
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true
 }`

Comment: Ok, I think I'm closer now. previous error dissapeared now i have this:

`Unknown option: base.isPluginRequired.`

and 

`A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }``

Comment: And then this: `{     
 "presets": [ ["@babel/preset-env", {             
   "forceAllTransforms": true,             
   "targets": {                 
    "node": "current"             
   },
   "sourceMaps": true     
   }
  ]    
 ]

}`